# Problems with my first python script

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple grading script based off an existing script that i found in a tutorial online. The goal is to ask the user their score and give the corresponding grade.

Here is the original code:

```
def letterGrade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    else:   # grade must be B, C, D or F
        if score >= 80:
            letter = 'B'
        else:  # grade must be C, D or F
            if score >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            else:    # grade must D or F
                if score >= 60:
                    letter = 'D'
                else:
                    letter = 'F'
    return letter
```

***this btw didnt work at all and i really dont get the "def" command since its not mentioned again? No errors***

Anyway, here is my new modified code from what i have been learning from books and online...

```
score = float(input("What is your score"))
if score >= 90:
    letter = 'A'
else:   # grade must be B, C, D or F
    if score >= 80:
        letter = 'B'
    else:  # grade must be C, D or F
        if score >= 70:
            letter = 'C'
        else:    # grade must D or F
            if score >= 60:
                letter = 'D'
            else:
                letter = 'F'
print (letter)
input ("Press Enter to Exit")
```

***This code doesnt work either, but at least it is asking for user input now.  No errors***

What am i missing here?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Hey and welcome, what do you mean by not working? What are you experiencing?

Comment: I tried your second one, and it's working for me. Why don't you think it's working?

Comment: `def` is used to define a function.  You'd need to call that function.

Comment: `def` defines a function/method in Python. You need to *call* the method to use it. From the original code, at the bottom of the script if you just did `print(letterGrade(90))`, you probably would have gotten an output. However, with this in mind, I think you really need to re-visit your tutorials to understand certain fundamentals of the language. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is the official tutorial.

Comment: Perhaps you intend your second code to repeat automatically. If so, you need to put it in a loop.

Comment: your logic could be transformed to ranges (`< >`) using `elif`

Comment: @Abdelouahab If this is from a tutorial, my hunch is that the tutorial hasn't introduced `elif` yet and uses this example as a motivation for that construct.

Answer (score 1):

The `def` keyword introduces a function. In order for your script to work interactively, can you call the `letterGrade` function like this:

```
def letterGrade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    else:   # grade must be B, C, D or F
        if score >= 80:
            letter = 'B'
        else:  # grade must be C, D or F
            if score >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            else:    # grade must D or F
                if score >= 60:
                    letter = 'D'
                else:
                    letter = 'F'
    return letter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    score = float(input("What is your score? "))
    print letterGrade(score)
    input ("Press Enter to Exit")
```

Here, the `__name__ == '__main__':` block will be executed when you invoke your script from the command line (`python your_script_name.py`)

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's first start with some pseudo code, I always try to pseudo code my problems and draw them out as much as possible, it helps me and it might help you. So the grading scale you seem to have implemented is something like this. If you have a grade lower than 100 but greater than or equal to 90 it is an A, lower than 90 but greater than or equal to an 80 it is a b, so on and so on. Let's use conditional statements for this. You can nest it like you had, but setting up the order of conditions may be what you need. So if the grade is not greater than or equal to 90, then the grade can only be lower than 90, thus a B, C, D or F.

```
if (grade >= 90):
    letter = 'A'
elif (grade >= 80):
    letter = 'B'
elif (grade >= 70)
    letter = 'C'
elif (grade >= 60)
    letter = 'D'
else:
    letter = 'F'
```

So with these conditional statements we go through the process of finding the grade, as explained a bit above the code, if the user does  not have a grade greater than 90, it hops to the next elif which checks if it is greater than or equal to 80, so on and so on, if grade at one point not greater than or equal to 60, then all other values lower than 60 will be an F.

Now to cover 'def'. You use def to define a function. Here is a generic layout:

```
def functioname(parameters, parameters):
    stuffgoeshere
```

Now, the parameters are optional, it all depends if you need to pass any data to the function, in your case, you are passing the grade of the user:

```
def gradeLetter(grade):
    if (grade >= 90):
        return 'A'
    elif (grade >= 80):
        return 'B'
    elif (grade >= 70)
        return 'C'
    elif (grade >= 60)
        return 'D'
    else:
       return 'F'
```

At this point you can call the function, passing in the value the user typed in. We return the character in the function, so that you can assign it to a variable to print it, or you can just print it within the function, whichever is your preference.

```
g = input("Please enter your grade: ")
l = gradeLetter(g)
print("Your letter grade is " + l)
```

Hope this helps you out. If you have any questions feel free to comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a noobie, let me give you a few tips.

1: SO is hostile to easily google-able things

If you google "python def" you'll see that it's the keyword for defining a function. What's a function? *google*. Oh, a function is a block of code that can be called multiple times.

```
def letterGrade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    else:   # grade must be B, C, D or F
        if score >= 80:
            letter = 'B'
        else:  # grade must be C, D or F
            if score >= 70:
                letter = 'C'
            else:    # grade must D or F
                if score >= 60:
                    letter = 'D'
                else:
                    letter = 'F'
    return letter

print(letterGrade(95)) # A
print(letterGrade(70)) # C
print(letterGrade(20)) # F
```

2: "else" and "if" can be combined in python:

```
def letterGrade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        letter = 'A'
    elif score >= 80:   # grade must be B, C, D or F
        letter = 'B'
    elif score >= 70:  # grade must be C, D or F
        letter = 'C'
    elif score >= 60:    # grade must D or F
        letter = 'D'
    else:
        letter = 'F'

    return letter
```

Comment: The only example of hostile behaviour I see on this page is your answer.

Comment: I'm not being hostile - I'm just stating the facts. SO usually doesn't take well to "I have no idea what X does, but this code using X doesn't work"

Comment: @vaultah Maybe you are just interpreting the tone of my answer wrong, but I'm not being hostile. I'm warning him that in the future, stating you have no idea what X does will draw downvotes. But you're right, I should have just left him to figure that out himself.

Comment: Dang it. Why is this being down-voted so much?

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer deserves a down-vote, but I could see how others might have interpreted it as being sarcastic. Look on the positive side. I think you get a badge the first time you delete a heavily down-voted post.

Comment: @RPGillespie now I realise that I could have misinterpreted you, and I apologise. In any case, answers should only contain relevant information. Though I have to agree that -5 is a bit too much.

Comment: First i want to say thanks to everyone that is trying to help me.  I am actually shocked and overwhelmed by the amount of help and code to sort through.  Im not even sure how to address everyones responses and questions regarding my question lol.  I dont know what an SO is...what i mean by "doesnt work" is that after i input my score and hit enter, no grade is displayed.  The elif statements are in the next tutorial so i wanted to understand how to do the if else first.

Comment: Actually im not even sure if that was the right place to comment lol?  Also what is all this talk about - (negative) scores on comments? This was the prev tutorial that i was trying to modify and do my own thing based off of the next tutorial. temperature = float(input ("What is the temperature"))
if temperature > 70:
    print("Wear shorts.")
else:
    print("Wear long pants.")
print("Get some exercise outside.")
input ("Press Enter to Exit")

Comment: @NoDisassemble Your second snippet of code works perfectly for me when I paste it into https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: Also SO = StackOverflow, and the negative scores are just SO drama - ignore it

Comment: @RPGillespie Thanks again RPGillespie, and you were right, my codes been working all along.  Turns out in PyCharm i was working on my "grade" script but pycharm was running a prev script at the bottom! lol Not sure why they made that ide have the ability to do that, but whatever lol.  I answered my own question to this thread but its posted towards the top.  How can i close this...and delete it forever so no other human will ever find my sad sad mistake? lol

Answer (score 0):

Omg hoooooooooooly crap!  I need to apologize for wasting everyone's time. RPGillespie was correct, my code was working this entire time.  Im new to using PyCharm and for some reason its set up in a way that you can be doing code at the top for one project, but actually "running" the code for a different project at the bottom.  Iv been running the wrong code this entire time...day wasted!!! =(

I will say that i wont be making that mistake anymore.  Geez, what a fiasco!!!

Thanks again for EVERYONE'S help and warm welcome.  I will admit that as i am new to this forum, i am not new to forums in general.  And its nice to not get eaten alive for asking a "noob" question or not knowing the un spoken rules of said forum.  Its nice to find a place that actually tries to help its members.

My sincerest apologies again, i promise my next problem/question wont be wasting this forums time =).

iv undoubtedly earned the badge of "DOH" and "Facepalm".